# docker/nodejs/mongodb deployment : MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

**update 2**

I face another error,
if I use path as follows, I will get "invalid volume specification" error
even change path to "C:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/", the init-mongo.sh will not be executed, then I get "UserNotFound: Could not find user "xxxx" for db "admin"

```
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - dbdata:/data/db
```

so
I switch to linux container, and all error message are gone.

**update**

I've solved my problem after disable mongodb service on local host

```
net stop MongoDB
```

and use port 27017

```
mongodb:
....
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
.....
```

but I would like to know why I cant change port 27017 to others?
I change the port because if mongodb is running on my computer (using 27017 port), I will get the following error message, thank you.

```
for mongodb  Cannot start service mongodb: failed to create endpoint mongodb on network server_app_network: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)
```

**original**

I'm using docker windows container on windows 10.
After struggling for two days, I still cant deploy my project successfully.
my configuration is as follows, thanks for help ..

server.js

```
const dbUrl = "mongodb://mongodb:27018/";
mongoose
  .connect(`${dbUrl}mydb`, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(res => {
    db = mongoose.connection;
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  express-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: express-server
    container_name: express-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - app_network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    networks:
      - app_network
volumes:
  dbdata:
networks:
  app_network:
    driver: nat
```

after running docker-compose up --build -d

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                 NAMES
7fac2380c803        express-server      "node server.js"         57 seconds ago       Up 43 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                express-server
9afc21569a1a        mongo               "mongod --bind_ip_all"   About a minute ago   Up 57 seconds       27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27018->27018/tcp   mongodb
```

Comment: The `express` service start before `mongodb` ready. Try restart `express` service with command `docker-compose restart express`. Or search for `wait-for` docker compose solution.

Comment: @ hoangdv express service did restart several times, but still got connection error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass dbName in configuration.

```
mongoose.connect(
    connectionString,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      dbName: 'database-name', // IMPORTANT TO HAVE IT HERE AND NOT IN CONNECTION STRING
    },
    err => { throw err; },
  );
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried but still get the same error.  it works fine on my localhost, only get connection error when running in docker container

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble to solve this error, finally I realized that the error is related to docker network, I have shared a little information to solve this error in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74873511/15498144)