# MongoDB Cannot run tests when building Docker image - Server selection error: server selection timeout

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I'm running a mongo image in a container with this config:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=microservices
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

And I have started to build microservices with golang and I want to start dockerizing those as well to speed up the development process. However when I try to run this Dockerfile below it panics at the run test command with the error:

```
database url:  mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/microservices
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: 127.0.0.1:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }

panic: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: 127.0.0.1:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

The db connection works since when I try to run the test from the go files, they pass. There only seems to be any problem when I try to run them from the container when building it up.

```
FROM golang:1.18 as build

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN go vet -v /go/src/app/...
RUN go test -v /go/src/app/...

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /go/bin/app/authsvc /go/src/app/authentication/main.go

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11

COPY --from=build /go/bin/app/authsvc /
COPY --from=build /go/src/app/authentication/.env /
CMD ["/authsvc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change database url

try mongodb

```
database url:  mongodb://user:password@mongodb:27017/microservices
```

Comment: Yep I've tried it since I read it in other stack threads but it does not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Try host: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. I can still run the tests from goland, so everything can reach the db port from the outside, but in the dockerfile the tests fail with the same error

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you must check your default network ip with

```
docker network ls
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlcMv.png)

After get network id and use this command :

```
docker inspect <your network id>
```

Inside result schema get your Gateway ip

```
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "111.11.0.0/11",
            "Gateway": "111.11.0.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

and use that ip

```
database url:  mongodb://user:password@ < your Gateway ip > :27017/microservices
```